# Do I need to sanitize user string input on a ASP.NET API Endpoint? If so how?

Tags: asp.net, api, security, sanitization

I wrote a service that converts English to Pig Latin for my website. It's a API endpoint that gets a string posted to it.

I'm concerned that because anything can be sent by the user, unsafe code could somehow be sent and run on the server.

Do I need to sanitize the input under these circumstances?

```cs
//Here is the API Action.
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[Route("api/plconverter")]
public IHttpActionResult TranslateIntoPigLatin([FromBody]string english)
{
  string piglatin = convert_to_pig_latin(english);
  return Ok(piglatin);
}
```

```js
//Here is the AJAX call that gets made.
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/plconverter",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(($(this).val().trim())),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
     $("#pig_latin_output").html(data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: If you get it to convert `<script>alert('Oops!');</script>`, do you see a message box saying "Oops!"? It is more the client that you need to be careful of than the server. Oh, is there any use of a database where SQL parameters are not used?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no. I encode the output as HTML, but I'm more worried/uneducated about the server side. As in could the client somehow send and run unsafe code on my server.

Comment: If you sent the user input to a database, then there is a chance of SQL injection, which can result in code being run in the database, but they won't be able to run C# code unless you have deliberately made it that way.

Comment: You might find someone confident enough to write an actual answer at [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).